# Install MDT application based on Make/Model using SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, windows-10, mdt, mdt-2013

I am trying to install applications using Deployment Toolkit (MDT) 2013 Update 2, based on the specific Manufacturer and Model of the client computer. But the applications are not installing.

I have installed SQL Express using the default settings (which creates a database called SQLEXPRESS)

I have installed SQL Management Studio and given access rights to the database to an account called MDT_BA. As per the following article.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/itpro/windows/deploy/use-the-mdt-database-to-stage-windows-10-deployment-information

I have gone into the SQL Configuration Manager and enabled 'Named Pipes'

I have created an inbound Firewall rule for TCP port 1433 and UDP port 1434 and also added an inbound rule for "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\Sqlservr.exe"

I manually started the "SQL Server Browser" service.

I have created my MDT database using the following settings.

1. Server Name: testmdt01.test.local
2. Instance: SQLEXPRESS
3. Port: (blank)
4. Network Library: Named Pipes

I have run a Powershell command to query the Make/Model on my client machine.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Computersystem `
| Format-List Name, manufacturer, model, SystemType
```

...and then added the returned values into the MDT 'Make and Model' table

- Make = HP
- Model = HP ProBook 450 G4

Finally, I added a Task Sequence to "Install Applications" (Not sure if this is required) and set the value 'SkipApplications=YES' in the Custom.ini to skip the applications screen.

I have also checked the applications packages by installing in the traditional way using the Task Sequence.

Any pointers/help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Open the properties of the `HP ProBook 450 G4` inside the MDT database's Make/Model registrar and add the applications manually in the "Applications" tab as a "LiteTouch Application".